# jsrender iterate over list separated by comma

Tags: jsrender

I have json like below.

How can I iterate over tags which are single list separated by comma ?

I know if tags list is in form of nested array, it can be easy to iterate over using **{{for #data}}**

```
        var gdata = [
        { id: "1", width: "425",height: "640",src : "test/ocean-bridge.jpg" ,thumb : "test/ocean-bridge.jpg",type:"picture",tags:"dd,cc,brazil,malakand"},
        { id: "2", width: "500",height: "333",src : "test/modern-bike.jpg" ,thumb : "test/modern-bike.jpg",type:"picture",tags:"never,ever,who,when" }, 
        { id: "3", width: "500",height: "580",src : "test/clown.jpg" ,thumb : "test/clown.jpg",type:"picture",tags:"what,why,didit,pizza" },
        { id: "4", width: "640",height: "360",src : "test/html5.webm" ,thumb : "test/webm.jpg",type:"movie",duration:"10:11:12",tags:"never,ever,who,when"},
        { id: "5", width: "640",height: "360",src : "test/html5.mp4" ,thumb : "test/mp4.jpg",type:"movie",duration:"12:10:12",tags:"dynamic,static,who,when"}
       ];
```

Comment: Can't you apply a split (', ') to the tags before rendering the template?

Comment: thats what i was going to do, but is there a nicer way with js render ? may be some helper function ?

Comment: also i am not good with js, how can i parse my above jason so i get tags replaced by nested array ?

Comment: I'm on the mobile phone so I can't access the jsrender doc but I don't remember if jsrender has string manipulation methods such that

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into an array? You would loose the field names. How would you like it to seem?

Comment: gdata is returned by php with json encode. and before that in php , it is array returned by complex sql so for now, I iterated array in php to split string by coma and convert it into array and then json encode it which is ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975379.aspx

On the section "converters" you will find a suitable way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If what you are showing is javascript, which has been executed (whether in your js file, or in script code loaded using `$.getScript(...)`, for example) then the JSON has already been evaluated, and gdata is an array.

Just call `...render(gdata);`.

Alternatively you can call `...render([gdata]);` and then use `{{for #data}}` within the template. 
(Or `...render({ images: gdata });` and then use `{{for images}}` within the template...)

Did you look at the new [www.jsviews.com](http://www.jsviews.com) site? See these topics, for example:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrplaying
- http://www.jsviews.com/#rendertmpl

Of course, each `{ id: "1", width: "425",...}` is a javascript object, so you use things like `{{:width}}` to render out the fields. Not sure whether you would need to use a converter, though if you want you could do `{{myconverter:#data}}` to compute a rendered value from all the fields.

Comment: yes actually, some data is returned as comma separated from complex sql query , then returned array is json encoded and sent to browser which still treats it as string

Comment: So you don't have gdata as shown above, but rather gdata = "[{id: ...}]"?

So this problem is really not to do with JsRender. You may need to convert from string to object/array, for whatever purpose, not necessarily for JsRender. Looks like you should read up about JSON - and in particular JSON.stringify() JSON.parse.

You can consider
var myObjectOrArray = JSON.parse(myString)
or
var myObjectOrArray;
eval("myObjectOrArray = " + myString);